# Ruby: Is there a more elegant way of doing this loop & array?

Tags: ruby

Okay, this code gives me exactly what I want but it seems that it could be cleaner, so here is the code:

```
colour = ["red", "white", "orange", "black"]  
x=[]  
colour.each_with_index do |c, i|  
   x[i] = "<a href='http://#{c}.test.com'>#{c}</a>"  
end  
tags2 = x.join(", ")  
p "The code ==>#{tags2}<=== "
```

Any takers?

Comment: You may want to read the Enumerating enumerable series: http://www.globalnerdy.com/tag/enumerable/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tags2 = colour.map {|c| "<a href='http://#{c}.test.com'>#{c}</a>" }.join(", ")
```

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002189) just calls a block for every element in the array, then returns the result array.

Comment: thanks, very nice - i knew there was something better, i am trying to overcome my old style coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
tags = ["red", "white", "orange", "black"].map do |color|
    "<a href='http://#{color}.test.com'>#{color}</a>"
end.join(", ")
p "The code ==>#{tags}<==="
```